# SQL query question

Tags: query

I want to find the records of August birthdays in own table.I'm using Datetime Field.

```
Sample record:

01.08.2001
06.06.1985
26.08.1995

etc..
```

How should I do write a query?

Regards,

Comment: It is always best to mention what platform you are working in, as different platforms will have different solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the db server you're working with? In SQL Server there's the [MONTH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) function.

Your query could be something like:

```
Select *
from User u
where month(u.DOB) = 8
```

Comment: Concise + straightforward = +1 !!!

Comment: Thanks Rolando :-). Means a lot coming from a DBA with your experience.